# How to alloc a result of function to the member variable and validate in if statement in Swift

Tags: swift, allocation

How to alloc a result of function to member variable and validate in if statement in Swift

I used this syntax in objectiveC, but in Swift?

```
class PointClass {
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
    var z: Bool = false

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

    func getBol() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func toString() -> String {

        if (z = getBol()) == true {//like objc

        }

        return "x=\(x), y=\(y)"
    }
}
```

Comment: you are no longer allowed to do assignment = in an if because its easily confused with equality ==.  This is actually true of most modern C style languages.  Put the assignment on a separate line before the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in swift. You need to add separate line for this

```
func getBol() -> Bool {
return true
```

}

```
func toString() -> String {

  self.z = getBol()
    if self.z { // if this will true. if statement will execute

    }

return "x=\(x), y=\(y)"
```

}